# Java: cmd jdk and jre version difference

Tags: java, cmd

I was trying to run a simple hello world java program and I encountered an issue.

This is what I did:
[cmd code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJYIr.png)

Then I did some research and came to know that this happens because of the difference in the version of the java compiler and java runtime environment. Therefore I found this solution on stack overflow which again did not work:

[cmd code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikoKs.png)

Doing so gives the warning shown above.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The error happens because your Java compiler is for Java 15, while your Java runtime environment is Java 8. Classes compiled by a newer version (15) won't run on an older version (8). Make sure you are using versions that are compatible. I don't know what the solution was that you tried, but you're still using Java 8 to run the program.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but then why no error occurs when I run the file from ide (IntelliJ IDEA)?

Comment: Because your IntelliJ is configured to use the correct Java runtime environment. You probably have a Java 8 JRE installed on your system, which is found in the PATH (environment variable) before the Java 15 JRE.

Comment: But I had installed only one version of jdk and jre, then how come there are multiple versions now?

Comment: I of course don't know why you have multiple versions installed, but your screenshot clearly shows you do, even if you think you've installed only one version.

Comment: Yeah, because I bought my new computer a month ago and have installed java only once

Comment: Then maybe Java 8 was already pre-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is compiled with Java15 while you're using Java8 in your command file. Either change your environment variables in your operating system or change the Java version used by your IDE when you are building your project.

Comment: I am using notepad, then how do I change the java version?

Comment: @meetprakashshah See the [JDK installation instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-A7E27B90-A28D-4237-9383-A58B416071CA), particularly the part "Setting the PATH environment variable".

Comment: @meetprakashshah then download at least Eclipse IDE and work with that, it's free. Nobody in their sane mind would develop in notepad, especially while learning.

Comment: yeah, I work with intelliJ, I am developing in java since past year, I just wanted to learn cmd so I tried making a projet in notepad. However, I unistalled java and reinstalled and the issue is resolved now, thank you for your help